# How to customise UIDatePicker in Swift3?

Tags: swift3, uidatepicker

Is it possible to customise UIDatePicker like the image in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysmfo.png)?

Comment: better to make a custom picker!

Comment: @hamentmiglani that's what I thought as well, I will just use a UIPicker and supply the dates, but my problem is where can I get the calendar data. Appreciate your answer.